# Proof of a part of five lemma in commutative algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Part of Five Lemma: Using that the following diagram of $R$-modules and $R$-homomorphisms commute, where the rows are exact sequences

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
M_1 @>{f_1}>> M_2 @>{f_2}>> M_3 @>{f_3}>> M_4 @>{f_4}>> M_5
\\
@V{h_1}VV @V{h_2}VV @V{h_3}VV @V{h_4}VV @V{h_5}VV
\\
N_1 @>{g_1}>> N_2 @>{g_2}>> N_3 @>{g_3}>> N_4 @>{g_4}>> N_5
\end{CD}

I need to prove that:

(a) if $h_1$ is surjective and $h_4$ is injective then $\ker(h_3)\subset f_2(\ker(h_2))$

(b) if $h_2$ is surjective and $h_5$ is injective then $g_3^{-1}(\operatorname{im}(h_4))=\operatorname{im}(h_3)$

I already proved some more staff but I am only asking here what I did not do yet, any idea to show this?

*Edit:*
I already proved that if $x\in\ker(h_3)$ then $h_3(x)=0.$ Since $h_4f_3(x)=g_3h_3(x)=0$ then $h_4(f_3(x))=0$ so $f_3(x)=0$ because $h_4$ is injective. Then $x\in\ker(f_3)=\operatorname{im}(f_2)$ so $f_2(y)=x$ and I need to prove that $y\in\ker(h_2)$. to do it I am trying to use that $h_1$ is surjective so:

$g_2h_2(y)=0$ then $h_2(y) \in\ker(g_2)=\operatorname{im}(g_1)$ then $h_2(y)=g_1(z)$ and as $h_1$ is surjective then $h_1(w)=z$, then $h_2f_1(w)=g_1h_1(w)=g_1(z)=h_2(y)$ but I dont know how more to do.

Comment: In your description of the lemma you should include the fact that the rows are exact.

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Comment: I already proved that if $x\in kerh_3$ then $h_3(x)=0.$ Since $h_4f_3(x)=g_3h_3(x)=0$ then $h_4(f_3(x))=0$ so $f_3(x)=0$ because $h_4$ is injective. Then $x\in kerf_3=im f_2$ so $f_2(y)=x$ and I need to prove that y\in ker h_2. to do it I am trying to use that h_1 is surjective so:


$g_2h_2(y)=0$ then $h_2(y) \in kerg_2=Img_1$ then $h_2(y)=g_1(z)$ and as $h_1$ is surjective then $h_1(w)=z$, then $h_2f_1(w)=g_1h_1(w)=g_1(z)=h_2(y)$ but I dont know how more to do.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that, by exactness, $f_2(y-f_1(w)) = f_2(y) = x$, and by your equation $h_2(y-f_1(w)) = 0$, so $y-f_1(w) \in \ker h_2$. This takes care of (a).

For (b) one direction is easy: if $x\in \text{im } h_3$, then $x = h_3(y)$, and so $g_3(x) = g_3(h_3(y)) = h_4(f_3(y))$.

The other direction really used the hypotheses: Let $x$ be such that $g_3(x)=h_4(y)$. Then by exactness, $0=g_4(h_4(y)) =h_5(f_4(y))$, and so $f_4(y) = 0$ by injectivity. By exactness, $y=f_3(a)$. Then, we have, $g_3(x) = h_4(y) = h_4(f_3(a)) = g_3(h_3(a))$, it follows that $x-h_3(a)\in \ker g_3$, so $x-h_3(a) = g_2(b)$ by exactness. By surjectivity, $b = h_2(z)$, therefore we have, $x-h_3(a) = g_2(h_2(z)) = h_3(f_2(z))$, and so $x \in \text{im } h_3$.

Answer (score 1):

For part (a), you are almost there. You deduced (correctly!) that
$$
h_2(f_1(w))=h_2(y)
\iff
h_2(y-f_1(w))=0
$$
or, put differently, $y-f_1(w)\in\ker(h_2)$. But now, simply observe that
$$
f_2(y-f_1(w))
=f_2(y)-(f_2f_1)(w)
=x
$$
since the upper row is exact, hence in particular $f_2f_1=0$. This shows that $x\in f_2(\ker(h_2))$, as needed. In fact, part (a) can be strengthened to an equality (can you see why this is?).

Part (b) works in a similar way, using the below "trick".

---

The important "trick" here is to rewrite an equation of the type $h_2(f_1(w))=h_2(y)$ as $h_2(y-f_1(w))=0$. This is that case, since we are usually interested in vanishing conditions when dealing with exact sequences and such.